# Changing sql servers crashes sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, move

So I have two SQL servers, server A and Server B.  Server B is the newest one and the one we are moving things to.  I have moved over all the content databases and changed everything in central admin to point to the new SQL server.  I have even done scenario 2 of this tech document: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Man

As soon as I detach the old main central admin content database from SQL Server A SharePoint cant load the websites, and on the new server if I try to open a elevated SharePoint PowerShell window, I get the message on top of the window saying  Unable to load assembly group.  as soon as I reattach the old database everything works.

I find this odd as the old database doesn't have any connections, and the new one does.  Im stumped on this

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem here - mainly because of your last statement. It seems like your reference to new SQL instance is not being picked up (otherwise just attaching to the old instance would not work).  Have you tried using an Alias?  I would also review your SQL security and validate all logons and groups are present on the new instance.

Comment: So once I detached the old database I get "The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.” Even though the old database has no connections to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unclear but I'm going to take a stab at it anyway.

It sounds like your have not actually changed the instance for the Admin databases.  If you had updated the configuration they would point to the new server and re-attaching them to the old server would make no difference.

Once you remove your Admin databases you have "disabled" your farm so you wont be able to connect to it via PowerShell.  I recommend you add a SQL Alias to the box and make sure that it works with your original instance (update your SP references to use the alias).  Then do a backup / restore to the new instance and change your alias to point to the new instance.  If all is working now - you can update the reference again to point to the instance directly.

Comment: Jesus,  thank you for your response, and I think you are correct.  Im not sure where or how to make an alias to the new SQL server. Do you have a link or directions on how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Hope you figured this one out.  Alias can be created in DNS or you can do them directly on the machine that will communicate with SQL using cliconfg.exe (run from command line).  Technically MS has deprecated that tool - but it's still in every version of windows, it simply updates the reg key required for the Alias.